# Why can't git lfs find files?

Tags: git, git-lfs

Git LFS against Bitbucket has been working OK, but just now I got "Object does not exist."

What is happening? How do I resolve it?

```
> git lfs fetch --all
Scanning for all objects ever referenced...
* 780 objects found
Fetching objects...
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 37 skipped) 0 B / 0 B, 37.00 KB skipped               
[8a0b9504fbb28ce2679079b925eb83a807839f89189754d11c9f5bdb68bdccd0] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
[90a4eb135056cf62603145742fc418f744c7902a86f27494956e53d9e44a9a8f] Object does not exist on the server: [404] Object does not exist on the server
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of this:

> Typically, we send a 404 error when your client isn't properly
>   authenticated. You might expect to see a 403 Forbidden in these cases.
>   However, since we don't want to provide any information about private
>   repositories, the API returns a 404 error instead.

Maybe set your user name and password wrong, [sources](https://developer.github.com/v3/troubleshooting/)

Comment: The authentication is correct: Not only do `git` and `git lfs` work for me for most commands, but this specific command produced the following before the error (see my question, above) indicating that a connection was made  `Scanning for all objects ever referenced...  780 objects found`

Comment: @JoshuaFox - Well, no comment on your specific configuration, but just to discourage reading *too* much into what output you're seeing...  At least one implementation exists wherein credentials can be "good enough" for accessing the git repo but still be rejected when accessing the LFS store specifically. (The "known" case of this for me is TFS, where unqualified *username* or *domain/username* will clone the repo but LFS insists on *domain\username*...)